# getStringArrayExtra() always return null

Tags: java, android, dictionary, android-activity

I am trying to open new Google map activity from my main activity, I pass the Extras in the main activity and check the intent everything is fine and all the information is there.When the new activity opens, if I check the information using the debug I can see that everything is fine too yet, when I am using `getStringArrayExtra()` it always returns NULL.

Main Activity

```
mapIntent.putExtra("LAN_LIST", goodLan.toArray());
mapIntent.putExtra("LON_LIST", goodLon.toArray());
mapIntent.putExtra("HeadLine_LIST", goodheadline.toArray());
mapIntent.putExtra("Context_LIST", goodcontext.toArray());
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Map Activity

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    lan = intent.getExtras().getStringArray("LAN_LIST");//does not work
    lan = intent.getStringArrayExtra("LAN_LIST");//does not work too
    lon = intent.getStringArrayExtra("LON_LIST");//same
    Headline = intent.getStringArrayExtra("HeadLine_LIST");//same
    Context = intent.getStringArrayExtra("Context_LIST");//same
```

I am not posting the log because I don't have any exceptions, all the variables get `null` and that it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure, the data you passing are **StringList** so it converted to String array? I have doubt if the data are not List of String than it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the value as array you could try like this for all:

`mapIntent.putExtra("LAN_LIST", goodLan.toArray(new String[goodLan.size()]));`

Assuming the Lists contain only Strings, this will work.

Alternately, in your MainActivity you could pass them as ArrayList using

`mapIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("LAN_LIST", (ArrayList<String>) goodLan);`

And then you could receive them at MapActivity as `intent.getExtras().getStringArrayListExtra("LAN_LIST");`

Comment: I have no idea why but that worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to know it helped you. Do you think you could accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to pass the information as List.

Answer (score -1):

You also have to add the name of activity as parameter of the method *getStringArray*.

```
 lan = intent.getExtras().getStringArray(MainActivity.LAN_LIST);
```

Comment: the key string is not const, how do I do it then?

Comment: Made it const,still nothing.